# linux command which shows physical IP of system

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any command which determine physical IP of the system ( on each physical Interface)?

Actually I want to make a script which un plump all IP except physical IP.

Thanks in advance,
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

There will be one IP address for a server, since it is an entity in network for that server. To get the IP adrress in linux:

```
 hostname -i
```

Comment: This relies on name lookup of `hostname`. You would be surprised how easily this can break (misconfiguration for example), or might not be "the" IP you're looking for (e.g. in systems with more than one network adapter). Actually the manpage reads, "`Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses (-I) instead`".

Comment: Hi Steephen;Thanks for the answer.. but it did not work. I am getting loop back IP.. Actually I need only one physical IP; not all configured IP. I need only static IP of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> ...on each physical Interface...

That would be `ifconfig`.

You can also call `hostname -I` (note the uppercase "I"), which lists all configured IP's except loopback and IPv6 link-local.

Comment: Hi DevSolar;Thanks for the answer.. but it did not work. I am getting loop back IP.. Actually I need only one physical IP; not all configured IP. I need only static IP of the system.

Comment: @Deepak: `ifconfig` should list all configured interfaces. If you're only getting a loopback IP, something is very wrong with your setup (or your box doesn't have a network card ;-) ). But there's a principal problem with asking for "the" IP. A system could have multiple NIC's. Picture a firewall -- one IP to the WAN, another one entirely to the LAN. Which one is "the" IP for the system? That's why documentation urges you not to rely on `hostname -i`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but ifconfig shows all ip list if you add a ip with ip addr command.

Comment: @Deepak: Sorry but I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry... its my mistake :-) .. it shows only one :-)